# Build a word generator!

Tags: code-golf, random

Your task is to create a program/function to replicate [this word generator](http://www.zompist.com/gen.html).

## Details

Your program/function take two input. One input is the `categories`. The other input is the `syllable types`.

#### Categories

`categories` will consist of classes of letters.

For example, `V=aeiou` means that the letters `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, and `u` will be classified under the category `V`.

- Each category will have a 1-letter name in **UPPERCASE**.
- The letters it contains will all be in **lowercase**.

#### Syllable types

For example `CV` would mean that the syllable will consist of a letter in category `C` and then a letter in category `V`.

For example, if `C=bcd` and `V=ae`, then the syllable can be `ba`, `be`, `ca`, `ce`, `da`, or `de`.

#### Your task

Your task is to generate 100 random words, each with a random length of 1-5 syllables, each chosen randomly in the syllable types, with the letter in each category chosen also randomly.

## Specs

- Any reasonable input/output format. I don't care how you input the list.
- All inputs will be valid.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest solution in bytes wins.

## Testcase

```
input1          input2    output
"C=st;V=aeiou"  "CV/CVC"  tasiti tese tossi tesis titi sese saset su sosastesisat sisosis sissa sata to sisas sese satetot sisuta tatote sa tetsesuti sossut ti seso tese tostutsasussi tutiset sasates tasa ta sa satso tastitta tetti sesita setetat tatsi tisetot sassu sessiso satessase sas ses totasta si tetsit titse sase totas sa ta sasesa tasa sostat sesi sissa tato tos tate sustosussatta sustas sassatote tesas sutat tatetatossos testisot tatta tissisisa sasese sesatus tito sisa satas sasisi so sasatustu sosses tetsa tese sestit sestu tisot sutastot sesu tet sotte sisute setotitsesi tita
```

Comment: @Maltysen Thanks, added.

Comment: @R.Kap "1-5 syllables, ***each*** chosen randomly in the syllable types"

Comment: Does the output have to be 100 *unique* words?

Comment: @R.Kap No. Random doesn't mean unique.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 80 bytes

gotta go fast

Input is a dictionary hash (for example, `{'C' => ['b', 'c'], 'V' => ['a', 'e']}`) and a list of syllable structures (for example, `['CV', 'VC']` or `%w{CV VC}`.

```
->c,s{100.times{puts (0..rand(5)).map{s.sample}.join.gsub(/./){|e|c[e].sample}}}
```

For sample input:

```
c = {
    'C' => %w{r s t l n},
    'V' => %w{a e i o u}
}
s = %w{CV CVC}
```

This produces a sample output:

```
salsun
lonlutunonnus
solitlaton
rusitar
lotol
ris
relussetsa
tanotte
nasun
sur
lusin
tuslu
nerunol
sorrelussenu
ni
nanro
nulila
ritlalatiso
nururlontensa
lilas
tatsisuto
lel
rerlisletnut
ler
netlo
sorora
surot
tilsasotisi
rilnolrati
lasrare
totni
surreratlaral
li
tullatilro
rusenoreto
lulnunen
nortille
tut
sanitare
soniserloras
tiritrattitsis
ratretrate
tesne
lastinsolta
sinirsitur
lulesuleno
li
sirurata
nutesnisitur
rulunna
natneretasi
lonre
les
laruletan
nitis
tarletu
tonrora
la
senru
seltotoniles
teransotutel
re
lulsirnilletus
nunanurlon
nunlortotsonna
nolun
tolso
nas
leltirninara
neltinlesla
lulutsisot
lesulusutnis
nolu
nun
tituntillini
ralteres
sasnirosse
tutorlari
nonlelletottan
lirsetutit
so
le
setse
susritterlilu
lorrirotri
linuritlilrat
rernilnelnutel
sulolletrolo
nisatellilru
tulene
tetnan
lisotoslersor
nerlani
ne
tunoletso
nonlontaroltun
rirrostarset
sotlonsiro
net
sutona
```

Comment: No sample output? :(

Comment: @KennyLau All right, if you insist...

Comment: *You know words, you have the best words.*

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - 18 bytes

Takes input as a dict and then one structure per line.

```
V100ssmmO@QkO.zhO5
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V100ssmmO%40QkO.zhO5&input=%7B%22C%22%3A%22st%22%2C+%22V%22%3A%22aeiou%22%7D%0ACV%0ACVC&debug=1).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 117 bytes

<sup>(Also works in Python 2.)</sup>

```python
lambda C,T:[J(J(R(C[t])for t in R(T))for j in[0]*randint(1,5))for i in[0]*100]
from random import*
R=choice
J="".join
```

The lambda function takes the categories `C` as a dictionary and the syllable types `T` as a list of strings. It returns a list of 100 words. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY4/C4MwEMV3P8VxUxQpWugiOLmJOIi4pA7WPzRWk5CmlFL62W1iXO5@79097uRH3wU/b1N63ZZuvQ0dZGGd0JzkpCIZ1a0/CQUaGIeK1P6uZqNo1Aaq4wPjmsThxQ3YMYijqPUmJVawK6axVQqlA69K@7tg/ejlKeJpFoxvNvcWarAXJvLFDBOU@vHEELA0vHJLhaFFWWoMdSMTL/yFQDFrrOlqsdfycApnlU6VLtv6iQcglX3bXvW3Pw)

#### Ungolfed

```python
import random

def wordlist(categories, types):
    return [
        "".join(
            "".join(
                random.choice(categories[t])
                for t in random.choice(types))
            for j in range(random.randint(1, 5)))
        for i in range(100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 136 bytes

```js
document.write("<pre>"+(

c=>s=>eval("for(r=Math.random,i=100,o=``;i--;o+=` `)for(j=r()*5;j-->0;)for(t=s[r(k=0)*s.length|0];l=t[k++];)o+=c[l][r()*c[l].length|0]")

)({ C: "st", V: "aeiou" })([ "CV", "CVC" ]))
```

Takes an object for the categories and an array for the syllable types.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 134 bytes

```
(c,s,r=s=>s[Math.random()*s.length|0],t="01234")=>[...Array(100)].map(_=>t.slice(r(t)).replace(/./g,_=>r(s)).replace(/./g,s=>r(c[s])))
```

Explanation:

```
(c,s,                               // Parameters
 r=s=>s[Math.random()*s.length|0],  // Select random character
 t="01234"                          // Number of syllables to skip
)=>[...Array(100)].map(_=>          // Generate 100 words
 t.slice(r(t))                      // Skip random number of syllables
  .replace(/./g,_=>r(s))            // Select syllables randomly
  .replace(/./g,s=>r(c[s])))        // Select letters randomly
```

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 95 bytes

```
import Test.QuickCheck
e=elements
c#s=mapM putStr=<<(generate$resize 5$listOf1$e s>>=mapM(e.c))
```

The categories are passed as a function from `Char` to `String` and the syllables types as a list of strings, e.g.

```
cat 'C' = "st"
cat 'V' = "aeiou"
syl = ["CV","CVC"]
```

Usage example: `cat # syl` -> `tesat`. Or with function/list literals: `(\c->case c of 'C' -> "st"; 'V' -> "aeiou") # ["CV","CVC"]`. Note: the function prints the generated word to stdout. If you try this within ghci, the return value is also printed, but that's a feature of the REPL and not of my code.

Dealing with random values in a purely functional language like Haskell is usually awkward. Luckily `Test.QuickCheck` provides some random generators and combinators for them that hide all the nastiness in a monad.

How it works:

```
input:
  s: list of syllable types
  c: categories as a function from Char to String

        e s             --  pick a random syllable type from s
           >>=mapM(e.c) --  for each letter: apply c and pick a random letter
                            from the returned string. We now have a random
                            generator for a single syllable
       listOf1          --  make a list of syllables of random length with
                            a minimum of 1
     resize 5           --  limit the maximum size to 5 (the list is not simply
                              cut if it is too long, all lengths are equally likely
   generate             --  run the generator. We now have a list of 1 to 5 syllables
mapM putStr=<<          --  print the syllables.
```

I'm happy that it works at all, maybe there's room for improvement.

Some more examples:

```
*Main> mapM_ (\_ -> do (cat#syl) ; putStrLn "" ) [1..10]
sisatassetto
se
ti
taso
sittos
tuttuste
tottu
satutustittes
sutetsetusut
tattatosote
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.5, <strike>227</strike> <strike>223</strike> <strike>210</strike> <strike>206</strike> 201 bytes:

```
def k(u,*p):
 import itertools as i,random as r;y=[]
 for z in p:y+=[''.join(i)for i in i.product(*[u[i]for o in z for i in o])]
 for q in'1'*100:print(''.join([r.choice(y)for i in'1'*r.randint(1,5)]))
```

Takes the categories in as a Python dictionary (e.g `{'C':'hello','K':'hoop'}`) and the syllable types in as normal strings, with each separated by a comma (e.g. `'CK','CKC'`). Output is in the form of 100 lines, with 1 word per line. Will add detailed explanation later.

[Try it online! (repl.it)](https://repl.it/CLww/3)